# Microsoft Edge channels, pre stable versions

Tags: version, microsoft-edge

I can't seem to find any Microsoft Edge channels or beta versions except stable one. If they exist where can I find them? There was no problem finding these things for chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Preview bits of Microsoft Edge are *flighted* to Windows Insiders. If you would like to see these in-development features/changes earlier, you should [join the Windows Insider program](https://insider.windows.com/) (preferably from a separate partition, or on a machine that you're okay loading a potentially unstable OS onto). *Note that the Windows Insider program is a preview of forthcoming changes to Windows 10 as well, in addition to Edge.*

If you would like to know what is in-development, without becoming an *Insider*, you can do so by visiting our Platform Status page online at https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/.